# Google's C2DM for gaming

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I've been looking at Google's C2DM service for push notifications for an Android Application. However, in my scenario, my application is a game. Do you think C2DM would be infeasible for pushing game state notifications to my mobile game clients from the server? I'm developing a game as a project but it will not be a commercial game. Just a prototype.

If C2DM will not suffice, do you have any suggestions for pushing game state from a server to a multiplayer game running on an android phone? I've explored a TCP/IP connection but I've a feeling this will hammer the batter power. Polling initiated by the client won't be efficient as I need real-time updates.

Any advice greatly welcomed
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounts limits are set individually and these limits can be confirmed or increased on request. For example, I have a c2dm account which has a limit of "just" 100,000 c2dm messages per day. So far, I think the most I have used is about 60 (a day). I am also writing a game that uses c2dm for messaging (moving from google talk messages - which is a right cluster). I was actually advised to used c2dm by Reto of google fame - so I am hoping its suitable !! What is your game btw?

Comment: My game was a game where you can move about, and using gps, you could pick up items virtually, that were plotted within your proximity. I ended up using Client/Server with TCP/IP. Albeit, UDP would've been faster however you would need to handle flow control and retransmissions manually. Interesting project nonetheless. It's nice to know that C2DM is available. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: If you want to see c2dm in action, the download an app I've written called "Vera Alert" - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fawepark.veralert - and then fire off an http request like this : http://vera-alert.appspot.com/stat?msg=Hello&recipient=XXXXX where XXXXX is the code presented to you when you start the app. I have written this app so people can link their home automation system with their phone for near-immediate alerting if a pre-determined event occurs in their home.

Answer (score 2):

Note that to prevent abuse/misuse of C2DM, Google puts limitation on the overall number of pushes a single developer can send over a period of time and the number of pushes a single developer can send to a single user.

C2DM are not meant for high traffic updates, if your game will require updates every 5 minutes or more, then you should just maintain an open TCP connection yourself, it won't be that battery expensive since in that case it is likely the screen and CPU will take the most power. However, if your game is a real-time game (i.e. the game progresses in real time, irrespective of whether the user is logged on or not; not real time in the sense of RTS), and you only need to push updates once every couple hours or so, then C2DM will be quite suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Have you any idea of the limits? I know that a message size cannot exceed 1024 bytes, which is fine. However I cant find where the other limits are posted.